# What does this error mean? undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm currently doing a has_many :through association, and I keep getting this error

```
   NoMethodError:
   undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the way I relate my classes

MODELS:
   Patient

```
   has_many :patient_templates
   has_many :templates, through: :patient_template, dependent: :destroy
```

Template

```
   has_many :patient_templates
   has_many :patients, through: :patient_template, dependent: :destroy
```

Patient_template

```
   belongs_to :patient
   belongs_to :template
```

MIGRATION

Patient_template

```
   def change
    create_table :patient_templates do |t|
      t.datetime :delivery
      t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
      t.belongs_to :template, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
   end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks that worked, I just wasn't seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. You will need to pluralize your `has_many` through association like so:

template:

```
has_many :patients, through: :patient_templates, dependent: :destroy
```

Patient

```
has_many :templates, through: :patient_templates, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: the second one should be pluralize too